# Is there a way to "migrate" data after an initial upgrade migration?

Tags: migrations

I was hired into a role that has a Drupal 7 site that needed to be updated to Drupal 10. The project is an 8 month one.

I've done the initial process of creating a destination site, running /upgrade in the browser, and migrating the Drupal 7 database to the new destination Drupal 10 site's database.

We are about to go into testing and so I need to bring in all the data (Users, pages, forum posts, comments etc) that have been created the last few months into the new Drupal 10 site. I'll also need to do this one last time when we launch in a few months.

I haven't been able to find anywhere on how this might be done, where I can specify something like 'migrate and/or update only users.'

I thought drush might have something, but I didn't find anything.

Has anyone had a similar Drupal upgrade/migration timeline where they needed to periodically run a migration of an older site in order to keep the content and users current during development? Any help or guidance would be appreciated. I am new to Drupal and struggling to find helpful resources.

Comment: The migrate module keeps track of items via a source ID. If the second migration run IDs is new, new items are created. If the source IDs are the same as the initial migration, the items are updated. So, if you have both sites running and a new user is created on the D7 site, the D10 site migration should recognise this and be able to run again and just import the new user.

Comment: The question is describing a core capability of the migration system.

Comment: @2pha I initially used the Migration UI in the browser via the Upgrade. Is there a way to just do a migrate without going through the Upgrade path? Upgrade will overwrite everything on the Drupal 10 site each time it is used.

Comment: @cilefen If it is, I am unaware which is why I am asking. My only experience with a migration is with the UPGRADE option via the UI in the Admin Configurations where I put the source DB and the destination DB. I have not been able to find if there is a way to re migrate data outside of UPGRADE where the warning says the Drupal 10 DB will be overwritten, where I just want new and updates to migrate.

Comment: "Is there a way to just do a migrate without going through the Upgrade path?"... yes. Migrate can be used with many different sources, But you wont yet be able to do it all via an interface, you will have to write some code, or an easier option might be to write a config .yml file and use the [migrate plus module](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_plus). Just yesterday I used migrate to import users from a csv file. I stumbled across [this website](https://drupalmigrate.org/) a while back which you may find helpfull